# Is there a more elegant way of writting this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm doing Stanfords introduction to DB course and this is one of the homework assignments. My code does the job well, but I don't really like it how I reused the same SELECT-FROM-JOIN part twice:

```
SELECT name, grade
FROM Highschooler
WHERE
    ID IN (
        SELECT H1.ID
        FROM Friend
        JOIN Highschooler AS H1
            ON Friend.ID1 = H1.ID
        JOIN Highschooler AS H2
            ON Friend.ID2 = H2.ID
        WHERE H1.grade = H2.grade    
    ) AND
    ID NOT IN (
        SELECT H1.ID
        FROM Friend
        JOIN Highschooler AS H1
            ON Friend.ID1 = H1.ID
        JOIN Highschooler AS H2
            ON Friend.ID2 = H2.ID
        WHERE H1.grade <> H2.grade
    )
ORDER BY grade, name
```

This is the SQL schema for the two tables used in the code:

```
Highschooler(ID int, name text, grade int);
Friend(ID1 int, ID2 int);
```

I had to query all the Highschoolers that only have friends in the same grade, and not in any other grades. Is there a way to somehow write the code bellow only once, and reuse it two times for the two different WHERE clauses = and <>?

```
    SELECT H1.ID
    FROM Friend
    JOIN Highschooler AS H1
        ON Friend.ID1 = H1.ID
    JOIN Highschooler AS H2
        ON Friend.ID2 = H2.ID
```

*EDIT: We are required to provide SQLite code.*

Answer (score 4):

This is a "poster child" example for the `WHERE EXISTS` query:

```
SELECT name, grade
FROM Highschooler ME
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Friend F
    JOIN Highschooler OTHER on F.ID2=OTHER.ID
    WHERE F.ID1=ME.ID AND OTHER.Grade = ME.GRADE
)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Friend F
    JOIN Highschooler OTHER on F.ID2=OTHER.ID
    WHERE F.ID1=ME.ID AND OTHER.Grade <> ME.GRADE
)
```

An `EXISTS` condition is `true` if its `SELECT` returns one or more row; otherwise, it is `false`. All you need to do is to *correlate* the inner subquery with the outer one (the `F.ID1=ME.ID` part), and add the remaining constraints that you need (the `OTHER.Grade = ME.GRADE` or the `OTHER.Grade <> ME.GRADE`) to your query.

Answer (score 4):

This is a typical type of question about groups related to an individual.  When you are faced with such a question, one approach is to use joins (looking at things in pairs).  Often a better approach is to use aggregation to look at the entire group at once.

The insight here is that if you have a group of friends and all are in the same grade, then the minimum and maximum grades will be the same.

That hint might be enough for you to write the query.  If so, stop here.

The query that returns what you want is much simpler than what you were doing.  You just need to look at the friends' grades:

```
SELECT f.id1
FROM Friend f jJOIN
     Highschooler fh
     ON Friend.ID1 = fh.ID join
group by f.id1
having max(fh.grade) = min(fh.grade)
```

The `having` clause ensures that all are the same (ignore NULL values).

EDIT:

This version answers the question:  Which highschoolers have friends all of whom are in the same grade.  Your question is ambiguous.  Perhaps you mean that the friends *and* the original person are all in the same grade.  If so, then you can do so with a small modification.  One way is to change the `having` clause to:

```
having max(fh.grade) = min(fh.grade) and
       max(fh.grade) = (select grade from Highschooler h where f.id1 = h.id1)
```

This checks that the friends *and* original person are all in the same grade.

Comment: +1 yep, that's probably the best suggestion, as it properly exploits all the information we had about the data wanted to be returned, and it does so on the same layer of the query.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how I can use/adept your code. I tried various variations of it, and none of them returned the correct records.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can get more natural query shape when you turn some filtering joins into set operations like UNION or MINUS/EXCEPT. The query of yours could be for example written as (pseudo-code):

```
  SELECT H.id
  FROM Highschooler H
  JOIN .... | has a friend
  WHERE ... | in SAME grade

EXCEPT

  SELECT H.id
  FROM Highschooler H
  JOIN .... | has a friend
  WHERE ... | in OTHER grade
```

some SQL engines use keyword "MINUS", some use "EXCEPT".

But note that very like UNION, this will execute both queries, then filter their results. This can have different performance then a single do-it-all query, but mind that **not necessarily** worse. Many times I find it even having better performance, as 'excepting' over single column, especially sorted, is very quick

Also, if your DB engine permits, you might try to use a View or CTE to shorten your original query, but I do not see much sense in doing so, except for aesthetics

Answer (score 0):

Some databases support the minus keyword.

```
select whatever
from wherever
where id in
(select id
 from somewhere
 where something
 minus
 select id
 from somewhere
 where something else
 )
```

Other databases support the same concept, but with the keyword except, instead of minus.